# Change the port number of DynamoDB locally

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, port

How can I change the port number of dynamodb on my local machine? it is set for 8000 and want to change it. I'm on ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The `-port`option can be used to provide the some other port number other than the default `8000`.

```
java -Djava.library.path=./DynamoDBLocal_lib -jar DynamoDBLocal.jar -sharedDb -port 8001
```