# Change amazon/dynamodb-local Port

Tags: docker, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-local

How can I change the port dynamodb starts on through the Amazon Docker image?

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52406725/7933478), the `-port` option can be used when executing the dynamodb java file.

However, when running the docker image with this command: `docker run -p 8000:8000 amazon/dynamodb-local` I do not have the option of specifying the port dynamodb listens to, just the port connected between my host and the container.

Would I have to make my own Dockerfile, specifying the OS and installing dynamodb and whatnot, so I can run the java command and specify my port?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried the official image to override entry point but there was some unknown error, But you can good to go with this approach. 
Just create a New Docker image from `amazon/dynamodb-local` as a base image.
Build.

```
docker build -t mydb .
```

and run it

```
docker run -it --rm -p 8001:8001 mydb
```

Below is the Dockerfile

```
FROM amazon/dynamodb-local
WORKDIR /home/dynamodblocal
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "DynamoDBLocal.jar", "-port", "8003"]
```

As you will see the port.

[image]

Comment: I was wondering how you found out to change the `WORKDIR` to `/home/dynamodblocal/`, though I understood when I changed the `ENTRYPOINT` to `["/bin/sh"]` and was then able to use a shell to see the image's directory structure.

Comment: i did it using `docker inspect amazon/dynamodb-local`

Answer (score 8):

You don't need to rebuild the image. Doing

```
docker inspect amazon/dynamodb-local
```

shows that the Entrypoint is set as

```
  "Entrypoint": [
   "java"
 ],
```

So running the below command gives an error:

```
 $ docker run -p 8001:8001 amazon/dynamodb-local -port 8001
 Unrecognized option: -port
 Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
 Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

because we are trying to pass **-port** argument to **java** but we need to pass it to **DynamoDBLocal.jar**.

Once we know that, we can add the jar to the docker run and the following works:

```
$ docker run -p 8001:8001 amazon/dynamodb-local -jar DynamoDBLocal.jar -port 8001

Initializing DynamoDB Local with the following configuration:
Port:   8001
InMemory:       false
DbPath: null
SharedDb:       false
shouldDelayTransientStatuses:   false
CorsParams:     *
```

I would raise it as a bug but https://hub.docker.com/r/amazon/dynamodb-local/ doesn't mention a public github repo to raise the issue.

Comment: for those using `docker-compose`, simply add a `command` under the dynamodb service. E.g. `command: -jar DynamoDBLocal.jar -port 8001  # pass in custom port to dynamoDB jar file`

Comment: adding -port option to command fixed my problem thanks.

Answer (score 4):

For some reason `docker-compose` does not map ports to the host for dynamodb. The next configuration will not work for the `dynamodb-local` image:

```
    ports:
    - "9000:8000"
```

The workaround is to put the port directly to the command,
`-port 9000` is the same as `ports: - "9000:9000"` in docker-compose.

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  service-dynamodb:
    image: amazon/dynamodb-local
    image: "amazon/dynamodb-local:latest"
    working_dir: /home/dynamodblocal
    # -port {number} is the same as 
    # ports: - {number}:{number} in Docker
    command: "-jar DynamoDBLocal.jar -port 9000 -sharedDb -optimizeDbBeforeStartup -dbPath ./data"
    volumes:
      - ./data:/home/dynamodblocal/data
```